# ReactJS: How to create a transparent page?

Tags: html, css, redux, reactjs

I currently have a page and a button. Upon clicking a button, I would like to update a state property, and once it has been updated, the component will rerender and show the transparent page over the original page.

Would want transparent page like so:

[image]

So far thought up of something like:

```
render() {
if(this.state.buttonPressed) {
  return(
    <div style={styles.transparentPage}>
       //transparentPage content
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return(
    <div style={styles.originalPage}>
       //originalPage content
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this would completely remove the originalPage and be rerendered with the transparentPage. So what would be the correct/proper approach to implementing a transparent page over an original page?

Answer (score 1):

All you would need to do is have something like

```
render() {
  var overlay = this.state.buttonPressed ? <div className="overlay" /> : null;

  return(
    <div style={styles.originalPage}>
      {overlay}
    </div>
  )
}
```

and then in your css do:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(250,250,250,.5);
  z-index: 25;

}
```

just make sure your z-index of the modal is more then the overlay z-index so it doesn't make it transparent as well

Comment: Here is a pen using just html css http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/dObJre

Comment: And inside, I would have it like so `<div style={styles.originalPage}>
      {overlay} <div>Original content</div>
    </div>`?

Comment: exactly, all the overlay consists of is any dom element you want with the class added to it, since its fixed position it can be anywhere in the DOM tree and still produce the result you want. You just want to make sure it only is rendered in the dom when you want the overlay hence assigning it to a variable and using a ternary to decide wether it should be a element or null.